# Which node package contains babel-plugin?

Tags: babeljs

Previously I have used `babel-plugin` in CLI to bootstrap and test babel plugin. In which npm package it contains now?

Eg:

`babel-plugin init
babel-plugin test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was deprecated in babel 6 and can not be used. Use [generator-babel-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-babel-plugin) to bootstrap babel plugins